# Prevent Cross-Site (XSS) during Saving form data as xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xss

i want prevent xss attack.but when i want save form data,i convert the form data to xml.now i want ask it does not make a problem?
how can i prevent xss but converting data to xml?

```
oXmlDoc = parser.parseFromString($get(MasterObj + "txtScriptGroupXML").value, 'text/xml');
 var oXmlNodes = $(oXmlDoc).find("Root").find("Tb");
       var XmlNodesLen = oXmlNodes.length;
       if (oXmlNodes.length > 0) {
           xmlStr = "<ReportsEntity>";
           for (var i = 0; i < XmlNodesLen; i++) {
               xmlStr = xmlStr + "<ModifyCreditInput>";
               xmlStr = xmlStr + "<Type>" + $get(MasterObj + "CmbGroupCode").value + "</Type>";
               xmlStr = xmlStr + "<StartDate>" + SDate + "</StartDate>";
               xmlStr = xmlStr + "<EndDate>" + EDate + "</EndDate>";
}
 $get(MasterObj + "txtXml").value = xmlStr;

   return SaveMode;
```

Comment: What are you even asking? What is "xss protector"? Do you mean CORS? If so, why would CORS care about the content type?

Comment: i mean:I have methods in my code that prevent XSS. Can I convert For example input data in javascript into xml? Is there no problem?

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what your "methods" in your code are. Perhaps [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108835/how-does-cors-prevent-xss) is a good starting point?

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your application in web.config application.
Place below code in your  in web.config.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
          <remove name="X-Powered-By" /><!--To remove X-Powered-By from header to hide dev platform info-->
          <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```